# Mapping an org chart into a hash table

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

Hey all I'm trying to take an array of objects(employees) and map them to a new object in order to depict the hierarchy of the org. So each manager would have a key and an array attached to the key holding all the names of their reports.

I'm unsure why I am unable to push my employee names to their respective manager's array. This seems to set my object keys to arrays rather than 1,2,3,4.

Anyone pointers would be appreciated.

Repl.it: https://repl.it/JeMh/2

```
let data = [
  { 
    name: 'ceo',
    id: 1,
    mgr: null,
  },
  {
    name: 'vp1',
    id: 2,
    mgr: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'vp2',
    id:3,
    mgr: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'mgr',
    id:4,
    mgr: 2,
  },
];

function displayOrg(data) {
  let org = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let current = data[i];
    for(let key in current){
      if(org[key] !== current.id || current.mgr){
        org[current.id] = []
      }
    }
    for(let key in org){
      console.log(current.mgr);
      console.log(org[key])
      if(current.mgr === org[key]){
        console.log("THIS HAPPEN");
        org[key].push(current.name);
      }
    }
  }
  return org;
}


displayOrg(data);
```

`expected resulted: { '1': [vp1,vp2], '2': [mgr], '3': [], '4': [] }`

Comment: So what's the expected result out of `displayOrg`? Can you update the question to show how that would look?

Comment: You might want to use the `array.filter` function for each person to get an array with their direct reports in it.  Then you can go through and do whatever you want to in displaying your org chart. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

looks pretty straight forward:

```
function getMngd(data, mngrId){
  return data.filter(emp => emp.mgr === mngrId).map(emp => emp.name)
}

data.reduce((p,c)=>{
 const {id} = c;
 p[id] = getMngd(data, id);
 return p;
},{})
```